# Eigenvectors of similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices then every eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $B$.

Is the above statement is true? I know that similar matrices have same eigenvalue, but I'm not sure about the eigenvectors.

Comment: It's false. Exercise: come up with an example. Almost any pair of similar $2\times2$ matrices will do.

Answer (score 14):

You can, and often should, think of similar matrices $A,B$ as being matrices of a *same* linear transformation $f:V\to V$ in different bases of $V$. Then if $f$ has eigenvalues $\lambda$, the corresponding eigenvectors are (abstract) vectors of $V$, and expressing these in the bases used repectively for $A$ and for $B$ gives (concrete) eigenvectors for the matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively. It is clear that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues as $f$, which are independent of any basis, but what you are essentially asking is wheter the concrete coordinates of these vectors are the same in the bases used for $A$ and for $B$, and the answer is of course "no".

Comment: +1 A beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 12):

There exists an invertible (change of basis) matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{−1}BP$. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, $v\neq0$ and $Av=\lambda v$.

So, $(P^{−1}BP)v=P^{−1}B(Pv)=\lambda v$.

Hence, $B(Pv)=P(\lambda v)=\lambda Pv$.

Since $P$ is invertible, it is one-to-one, hence it cannot take a nonzero vector $v$ to $0$ (it already takes $0$ to $0$). Thus, $Pv\neq 0$.

Therefore, $Pv$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: should be accepted answer imo

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices, then they represent the same linear transformation $T$, albeit written in different bases. So really the two matrices have the same eigenvectors, they just look different because you're expressing them in terms of a different basis.

Comment: This is false, take a look at $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, S=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&5\end{bmatrix}$. Then $$B=SAS^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}3&-1\\9&-3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Eigenvector of $A$ is [$\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Matrix+%7B%7B3%2C-1%7D%2C%7B9%2C-3%7D%7D).

Comment: @Invisible surely you mean eigenvector of B? I don't see how that contradicts my answer though. I'm sure you would agree the corresponding eigenvector of $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, and we have $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, i.e. these two concrete eigenvectors are related by the change of basis matrix *you* provided.

Comment: If they are related by a (nontrivial) change of basis, @Chris, then it is not the same vectors. I think you are answering a different questions.

Comment: @ArcticChar a vector is not just its coordinates in some basis. To the linear transformation from Invisible's comment (written as A in one basis and B in another) we can associate an eigenvector to the eigenvalue 0. In the first basis this vector is written (1 0) and in the second basis it's written (1 3). It's the same abstract vector though. Do you also take issue with referring to the two matrices as the same linear transformation?

Comment: I guess the complaint by me is well explained in another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/255208/629362). Especially the last two lines.

Comment: @ArcticChar would it be better if my answer said "they just have different coordinate representations" instead of "they just look different"? In my mind I'm saying the same thing as Marc but given the sudden negative response (after 7 years!) I'd like to find where the communication is breaking down.

Comment: I really think that your interpretation is the wrong one. Using your logic every nonzero-vectors is an eigenvector of $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: This answers gained more attention because it is mentioned in a chatroom. Also , Invisible made an edit to the post which bumped the post to the first page, which also explains the situation (BTW I am very surprised that you are still responsive)

Comment: @ChrisBrooks, yes, I meant $B$ and you can simply visualize it by taking a projection on a one-dimensional space/line. All such projections have equal Jordan forms but they project to different lines.

Comment: You're basically saying that every automorphism is an identity, which is obviously false.

Comment: So, what we're all saying is that those aren't the same eigenvectors. These operators have the same effect on different eigenspaces.

Comment: I agree on the _abstract_ eigenvectors, but look at the sentence _concrete eigenvectors of the matrices_ $A$ _and_ $B$ _respectively_. Furthermore, [look](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22similar+matrices+can+have+different+eigenvectors%22&oq=%22similar+matrices+can+have+different+eigenvectors%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.15723j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The transition matrix is crucial.

Comment: @Invisible If you agree about the abstract eigenvectors being the same, then it seems the issue is that I should think of equality of vectors strictly as tuples of real numbers which are equal component-wise. I think this is a bad perspective, but I don't think this discussion is going anywhere so I'm going to move on and let the downvotes do their job.

Answer (score 3):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, and let $\Lambda = V^{-1} A V =  \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, but $\Lambda \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

False. For an easy reasoning, suppose $A$ is diagonalizable and $B$ is the diagonalization of $A$. $A$ and $B$ are similar by the definition of diagonalizable: there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$, and $B$ is a diagonal matrix.

Then the standard basis vectors are the eigenvectors of $B$, but clearly these need not be the eigenvectors of $A$. (In fact, if your claim was true, then the every eigenvector of a diagonalizable matrix would be a standard basis vector, which is false.)

Answer (score 0):

No. If that was the case, if a matrix was diagonalazible in one basis, it would be diagonalizable in every basis.

In order to be diagonalizable in basis B, for M an
$ n \times n $ we need a full basis of eigenvectors, i.e., n ( linearly -independent) eigenvectors $B_1, B_2,.., B_n$. If these were eigenvectors in every other basis B', then they would be a full basis in B' and so M would be diagonalizable in B' for every other basis B'.