When are similar matrices identical?
I understand that, just like an abstract vector is an invariant entity (while its concrete coordinate representation is basis-dependent), also a transformation is an invariant act (while its matrix representation is basis-dependent). Thus it can happen that the same transformation can be represented in two different bases with different (square) matrices, which are said to be similar. When this is the case, one can do a trick of taking a vector expressed in basis $b$, change its representation to basis $a$ by applying the change of basis matrix $C$, apply the transformation with the matrix expressed in basis $a$ and finally convert the output into the language of basis $b$ by applying the inverse of $C$, as follows:
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{[T]_{b}[x]_{b}=C^{-1}[T]_{a}C[x]_{b}}}$$
I am also aware that there are active and passive transformations, the former altering the object itself and giving off its coordinates elsewhere and the latter giving the coordinates of the unaltered object in another basis.
So far so good, but then when you study the chapter of transformations (say active transformations), you are told that each of them takes a given form and no reference is made to the basis, as if such form were basis-independent. I guess that this is because it is assumed that these matrices will be expressed in bases having as eigenvectors not only the same abstract vectors but also the same coordinate vectors.
For example, a counterclockwise 3D rotation is said to have this form:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\cos \theta }&{ - \sin \theta }&0\\
{\sin \theta }&{\cos \theta }&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}} \right)$$
But the guess is that that the author is assuming that the relevant basis is orthonormal and that the axis of rotation is aligned with the basis' Z axis, no matter how its X and Y axes are oriented.
In turn, the counterclockwise 2D rotation is said to have this form, without reference to any specific basis:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\cos \theta }&{ - \sin \theta }\\
{\sin \theta }&{\cos \theta }
\end{array}} \right)$$
But again this would be assuming that the relevant basis is orthonormal and that any 2D rotations share a coordinate eigenvector, even if it is the trivial one, the zero vector.
My questions are:

Are my above-mentioned guesses correct?
If one wanted to generalize when two similar matrices become identical (i.e. they don’t only carry out the same transformation, but also have the same numerical form), one way to do it would be to look for the case when the similarity transformation reduces to an identity, which seems to require that the active transformation as expressed in basis $a$ and the passive or change of basis transformation from basis $b$ to $a$ commute, as follows:

$${[T]_b} = {C^{ - 1}}{[T]_a}C = {C^{ - 1}}C{[T]_a} = {[T]_a}$$
If this were correct, I would wonder about the logical connection between the two things: this commutation and the fact that both bases share the same coordinate eigenvectors.


So far so good, but then when you study the chapter of transformations (say active transformations), you are told that each of them takes a given form and no reference is made to the basis, as if such form were basis-independent.

Whoever wrote this in the text you're studying was being sloppy. In the context of your examples of rotations it's tacitly understood that either the basis is just the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the author means "up to an orthogonal change of coordinates," and/or it's an orthonormal basis, but this should be made explicit.
As for your second question, the condition is easiest to state for linear maps $T, S$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space which are diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_n$ (with multiplicity). Then the condition is that $T = S$ iff we can find a basis of eigenvectors for $T$ which is also a basis of eigenvectors for $S$, with matching eigenvalues, or vice versa.
This is a special case of a more general statement about when $T$ and $S$ commute: with the same hypotheses, $TS = ST$ iff we can find a basis of eigenvectors for $T$ which is also a basis of eigenvectors for $S$ (with no condition on the eigenvalues), or vice versa. When this happens $S, T$ are said to be simultaneously diagonalizable.

You said "T=S iff we can find a basis of eigenvectors for T which is also a basis of eigenvectors for S, with matching eigenvalues". But I thought that this was the condition for pure similarity, with the difference btw similarity and identity being that for the 1st by "eigenvectors" we understand the abstract/invariant things while for the 2nd we mean the same coordinate representation. (Apart from eigenvalues being the same, too, in both cases.) Was I wrong or do you mean the same?

@Sierra: I don't quite understand your question. I mean "the same," as in identical, as in $T(v) = S(v)$ for all $v$. I am not talking about coordinate representations anywhere. The condition for two diagonalizable linear maps to be similar is that they have the same eigenvalues (with multiplicity); there is no condition involving the eigenvectors.

Thanks for your answer, I think we had a little misunderstanding. When I said, "do you mean the same", I meant "do you mean the same as what I said in my comment", i.e. matrices are similar if they have identical eigenvalues but also the same abstract eigenvectors, even if the latter's coordinate representation differs (otherwise the matrices would have to be identical).

@Sierra: what do you mean by "the same abstract eigenvectors"? I think you're getting a little tangled up about what is and isn't basis-invariant and about the meaning of various equivalence relations in play. If two diagonalizable linear maps have the same eigenvectors and the same eigenvalues, as in the same, as in the same elements of the vector space $V$, then they are identical, not just similar. This is, again, a statement that does not involve coordinate representations at all.

The corresponding statement for matrices is that if two diagonalizable matrices have the same eigenvectors and the same eigenvalues, as in the same, as in the same column vectors with the same entries, then they are identical. On the other hand the condition for them to be similar is that they have the same eigenvalues (with multiplicity). That's it. No condition on the eigenvectors.

Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255172/eigenvectors-of-similar-matrices/255208#255208 for the difference I am relying on btw abstract eigenvectors (elements of a vector space) and concrete eigenvectors (their coordinate representation). In those answers people assume that similar matrices (same maps with different numbers) also have as eigenvectors the same elements of vector space albeit with different numbers.
